# get_the_ID() is working on my local development but not on staging server

Tags: custom-post-types, get-the-id

Great to see a StackExchange for WP! Ok so I'm working on pulling images and dates from piklist custom post types and I got this working on my local, BUT when I move it to WPEngine I get a white page until I take the code out. The date code doesn't throw a blank page but won't pull the dates entered. Can anyone tell me what about this code may be causing this? Thanks in advance!

**CODE**

**single.php**

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

  <?php

    $image_ids = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'my_media', false);

    foreach ($image_ids as $image)
    {

      echo '<img src=" ' . wp_get_attachment_image_src($image, 'large')[0]  . ' "/>';

    }
  ?>

  <?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'my_date', true); ?>

  <?php get_template_part( 'content', themeblvd_get_part( 'single' ) ); ?>

  <?php themeblvd_single_footer(); ?>

  <?php if ( themeblvd_supports( 'comments', 'posts' ) ) : ?>
    <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>
  <?php endif; ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: I used to make the same array de-referencing mistake many a time while we used WPEngine as our host. Gladly, we got of WPEngine and moved to a real host that supports the 5.5 families and beyond.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is this part:

```
wp_get_attachment_image_src($image, 'large')[0]
```

In old PHP versions like 5.3 and below, you cannot reference an entry (`[0]`) from the returned array of a function. The problem is that WP Engine is *still* on PHP 5.3, which [reached end of life recently](http://php.net/archive/2014.php#id2014-08-14-1) and doesn’t get security updates anymore. For the history see [PHP 5.3 - Thanks for all the Fish](http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/178-PHP-5.3-Thanks-for-all-the-Fish.html).

You have two options:

1. Find all occurrences of modern syntax and rewrite them to make it compatible with 5.3. In this case:

   ```
   $img_data = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image, 'large');
   $src = $img_data[0];
   ```
2. Switch to a newer PHP version, preferably 5.5. If your current hoster cannot do that find a better one.

Comment: I had a feeling it was compatibility issues. You don't have a good idea of best work arounds do you? I'm going to ask the google now.

Comment: @TuckerJones I have added an example to my answer. But there may be other places you have to change.